Create texture from RenderTarget with transparent background
I created a SceneCaptureComponent2d, a RenderTarget, and was able to take picture of a static mesh and put it into texture, though it looks like this

Which actually is a black square with hole. And I need quite the opposite - picture without black background. Not material, not some fancy effect, just a simple texture.
